# Finding the rational values of constant for which these constants are roots of equation

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

Problem :

Determine all rational values for which $a,b,c$ are the roots of $x^3+ax^2+bx+c=0$

Solution :

Sum of the roots $a+b+c = -a$ ........(i) ( Since , as per question $a,b,c$ are roots of equation and we have to find values )

$\sum_{a,b,c} ab = b ........(ii)$

$abc= -c \Rightarrow ab = -1 \Rightarrow a =\frac{-1}{b} .....(iii)$

Solving (i),(ii) and (iii) simultaneously we get an equation which is biquadratic in "a" which is :

$2a^4-2a^2-a+1=0$ Here we can find that $a = 1$ is a factor of this equation and by long division of polynomial we can divide $a-1$ with the given biquadratic we get cubic polynomial in a which is $2a^3+2a^2-1$ ...

Please guide further and suggest whether this is correct or not.. Thanks...

Comment: I haven't really thought about it much, but in case $(iii)$, one learns that $ab=-1$ *or* $c=0$, so there's another case to consider.

Comment: Right, so if $c=0$, then  $b=0$ and $a=0$. Remember, in the case you were doing, that you can use the Rational Roots test, so life shouldn't be so bad.

Comment: @TedShifrin:(The $c=0$ case also leads to the solution $x^3 + x^2-2x$, but I agree that Rational Roots is the way to go.)

Comment: I'm confused. (ii) gives $ab=b$ and (i) gives $a+b=-a$. So, either $b=0$ and $a=-a$ or $a=1$ and $1+b=-1$. Oops, I previously did that one wrong in my head. My apologies.

Comment: BTW, @JasonDeVito, I knew your adviser years ago when he was a postdoc at Berkeley and I was a lowly grad student :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither $-1$ nor $1$ is a solution to your final cubic, so this calls for the use of the [cubic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function).

$$a = 2, b = 2, c = 0, d = -1$$
$$\Delta_0 = 2^2 - 3(2)(0) = 4$$
$$\Delta_1 = 2(2^3) - 9(2)(2)(0) + 27(2^2)(-1) = 16 - 108 = -92$$
$$C = \sqrt[3]{\frac{-92 + \sqrt{(-92)^2 - 4(4^3)}}{2}} = \sqrt[3]{\frac{-92 + \sqrt{8208}}{2}} = \sqrt[3]{\frac{12\sqrt{57} - 92}{2}} = \sqrt[3]{6\sqrt{57} - 46}$$

We can divide $8208$ by $-27a^2$ (or $-108$) to get the equation's discriminant, $-76$. This means the equation has one real root and two complex roots. That real root is given by:

$$-\frac{1}{6}\left(2 + \sqrt[3]{6\sqrt{57} - 46} + \frac{4}{\sqrt[3]{6\sqrt{57} - 46}}\right)$$

A number which is definitely not rational. So you have found the only rational root, 1.

Comment: By the Rational Roots Theorem, the only candidates for rational roots of the quartic are $\pm 1$, $\pm\frac{1}{2}$. Of these, only $1$ works.